Are there infinitely many numbers for which there is no power of 3 with the hamming weight of its binary representation equal to that number?
Inspired by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22629/are-there-primes-of-every-hamming-weight#:~:text=Standard%20heuristics%20on%20the%20distribution,Hamming%20weight%20h%E2%89%A53, I decided to look at hamming weights of powers, as they are much sparser than primes.
In particular I looked at powers of $3$, and for exponents less than $10^4$, the smallest integer which is not a hamming weight of a power is $7$.

 Is there a power of $3$ with the hamming weight of its binary representation equal to $7$?
Disproven in the answers.


Are there infinitely many numbers for which there is no power of $3$ with the hamming weight of its binary representation equal to that number?


A011754 is the sequence of Hamming weights of $3^n$. It states:

Senge & Straus prove that for every $m$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $a(n) > m$. Dimitrov & Howe make this effective, proving that for $n > 25$, $a(n) > 22$.

It follows that there is no $n$ with $a(n)=7$.

Thanks for answering! The second question still remains.
